# Difficulty in choosing which RF 13.56 Mhz Plasma Jet configuration to use

Tags: electric-fields, potential, thermal-radiation, plasma-physics, nuclear-engineering

[image: Configuration of RF Plasma jets]

Can anybody explain why we can't use Molecular gases as our operating gas when we choose figure 1? Is it possible to use figure 1 using molecular gases such as O2 and Air or should we stick to the design using figure 2? The paper where this screenshot comes from states this but didn't add any reference. Link to the paper is here: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0741-3335/47/12B/S38

"Two basic construction principles have been investigated. The first is characterized by a pair of
outer ring electrodes (rf and grounded) and operates exclusively with rare gases (e.g. argon) as
feed gas (figure 1, left). Due to the field geometry, electrical breakdown can occur through the
ambient air on the outside of the capillary if the source is operated with molecular gases. The
rf voltage is coupled to the source via a matching network to one of the outer ring electrodes
around a quartz capillary (inner diameter 1.0 mm). The gas flows through the capillary. The
capillaries can be arranged in arrays. The second source geometry (type II) is distinguished by
a centre rod electrode inside the quartz capillary (inner diameter 2.5 mm) and one grounded
ring electrode (figure 1, right). With this geometry the set of operating gases is extended to
molecular gases (e.g. N2, air)."

Thanks